# JAXB: Unmarshalling multiple elements with distinct attribute into separate fields within the same java class

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am consuming a soap service that returns the following response

```
<...>
    <SearchResult>
        <Score>1</Score>
        <HasImage>False</HasImage>
        <Field Name="BillToCode" Type="User"/>12</Field>
        <Field Name="BrokerNumber" Type="User"/>broker12</Field>
        <Field Name="DeductionDate" Type="User">2011-01-12</Field>
        <Field Name="DeductionNumber" Type="User">deduction</Field>
    </SearchResult>
<...>
```

And I would like to map it into a easy to use java class.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="SearchResult")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SearchResultElement
{
    @XmlElement(name="Score")
    private  int mScore;

    @XmlElement(name="HasImage")
    private  boolean mHasImage;

    // ???
    private  String mBillToCode;

    // ???
    private String mBrokerNumber;

    // ???
    private String mDeductionDate;

    // ???
    private String mDeductionNumber;
}
```

I already use JAXB and I would need some insight on how to avoid creating a mess.

Mapping the Fields into an hashmap could also prove a usefull, but I would like to avoid mapping the Fields into an array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With **MOXy** you could use the [`@XmlPath`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/XPath)  annotation, [as described in this post](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html).

e.g.

```
@XmlPath("/SearchResult/Field[@Name='BillToCode']/text()");
private String mBillToCode
```

EDIT:
MOXy supports matching of one attribute, so you unfortunately can't write `@Name='BillToCode' and @Type='User'`.

Comment: +1 - MOXy currently supports matching on one attribute so you could do:  @XmlPath("Field[@Name='BillToCode']").  For more information see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

Answer (score 1):

MOXy currently supports matching on one attribute then whats the alternative for checking for more than one attribute matching?
like @Name='BillToCode' and @Type='User'